# Background Image wont display with HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css, image

I'm trying to add an image to my "welcome" ID but the image wont display.

Here is my CSS and HTML:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}
.header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 35px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
#welcome {
  background-image: url(../images/Welcome.jpg);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Template</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="design.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="simplegrid.css">
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="header">
    <div class="grid grid-pad">
      <div class="col-1-3">
        <h1>Logo</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="col-2-3">
        <a href="#about">About</a>
        <a href="#whatwedo">What we do</a>
        <a href="#whoweare">Who we are</a>
        <a href="#work">Our Work</a>
        <a href="#contact"> Contact Us</a>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
  <section id="welcome">


  </section>

</body>

</html>
```

I've tried both single and double quotes inside the url box. I have also added the image to the body using  tags and it displayed that way, but for some reason it wont display through the style sheet. I have also tried embedded and inline css, neither has worked. 
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you made sure the url is correct? The tag has nothing in it also...

Comment: try adding some content on the section mate

Comment: You need to add some content. Also make sure the path to the image is correct.

Answer (score 0):

The section will just take a 0px width and height since it doesnt have any content. Either add come content, which will then force it to expand to its height, or gives fixed heights, like below. That should ideally work.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}
.header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 35px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
#welcome {
  background-image: url(data:image/jpeg;base64,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);
  width: 400px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Template</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="design.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="simplegrid.css">
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="header">
    <div class="grid grid-pad">
      <div class="col-1-3">
        <h1>Logo</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="col-2-3">
        <a href="#about">About</a>
        <a href="#whatwedo">What we do</a>
        <a href="#whoweare">Who we are</a>
        <a href="#work">Our Work</a>
        <a href="#contact"> Contact Us</a>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
  <section id="welcome">

  </section>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason it won't display is because you applied `height: 100%` to `#welcome`, however, the browser doesn't actually know what that size is because percentage values are relative to the immediate parent. In this case the immediate parent is the `body` tag which you've also set to `height: 100%`, but yet again the browser can't calculate that either. This time it's because you have not defined the height of the `body` tag's parent, which is the `html` tag. So because the `html` tag's height is undefined and it is the parent of the `body` tag, the browser has no reference value to calculate 100% height from. So both the `body` tag and `#welcome`'s heights are `0`.

You can set your CSS like so.

```
html {
  min-height: 100%; // this will reference the viewport but could become bigger than viewport depending on your content
}
body {
  height: 100%;
}
#welcome {
  height: 100%;
}
```

Another option would be to set `#welcome` to be 100% of the viewport like so:

```
#welcome {
  height: 100vh;
}
```

Hope this helps.